# Can someone help me? Import xlsx spreadsheet with password, to Acccess / Vba. It looks like the Excel .xls format works but the .xlsx doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, import, passwords, xlsx

Good morning, I'm in Access / Vba needing to import an xlsx spreadsheet with password to an Access table, I can't, xls spreadsheet works but xlsx doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```vb
    'This code does not work.
    Function ImportProtected(strFile As String, _
    strPassword As String)
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Dim oExcel As Object, oWb As Object, wkb As Object
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oWb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strFile, Password:=strPassword)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=5, _
         TableName:="tmpTableName", FileName:=strFile, _
         Hasfieldnames:=True, Range:="Q1!C:G"
    Set exApp = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    exApp.Password = strPassword
    exApp.Save
    exApp.Close
    oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60191249/edit) your question and add your nicely formatted code there instead of leaving it in a commend, all jumbled up.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what is the error. Saying that is does not work does not really help. When I look at your code I do not understand why are you opening the same file twice.
This code should not be there:

```vb
    Set exApp = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    exApp.Password = strPassword
    exApp.Save
    exApp.Close
```

You are trying to open a file which is already open and locked. This may be the error.